# Monitor stays black after update (18.04)

Tags: drivers, monitor

I started my laptop after 3 months off time and I have serious problems with my monitors. When I start my laptop plugged in to a docking station (with 2 monitors), all monitors stay black after login (even the integrated display). Restart is the only solution for now.

The only way I can work for a while is that I switch on my Laptop and then plugin to the docking station. But when I lock my screen (with "Windows" - oh, how I miss that!! - and "L"), I cannot work anymore with my laptop, since all displays stay black --> restart.

It's a DELL Laptop and DELL monitors (all same brand - Apple style). So, I'm wondering what went wrong in updates of the last three months.

Thanks for any hints!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have your power management set to sleep or turn hard disk off after a set time.  Dell *used* to have major issues with laptops resuming from sleep or hibernate, along with Toshiba laptops having similarly bad sleep/resume problems.